# React DataGrid Single Row Customization

Tags: css, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Working with a Material UI react data grid for the first time and I need to apply a custom background color to only the first 3 rows, each being a different color. The custom coloring of these rows is static, nothing that's supposed to happen after an event takes place. Is there any way to point to only one row and apply a background color to it from my scss file?

On a slightly related note, how do I extend column separators so they fill the data grid?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use nth-child(1){}

for style the number 1 child.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I was able to style all three this way.